# Pigeon Hole Principle question, proving it is possible to select a number of points on a plane such that they are all interior to a circle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Thirteen points are given in the plane so that among any three of them there is a pair whose distance apart is less than 1. Prove that it is possible to select seven of the points so that they are all interior to a circle of radius 1.

I've experimented with PHP, but I didn't get much out of it...

Just for the record, this isn't a homework question, I stumbled upon it when I was doing some other PHP questions (no solution was given :( ...)

Comment: Hint: Pick any point ($A$) and consider the circle of radius 1 about $A$. What can you say if there is a point $B$ that lies outside this circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Pick any point ($A$) and consider the circle of radius 1 about $A$.

Case 1: All points lie in the circle, we are done.

Case 2: There is some point $B$ that doesn't lie in this circle.

> Claim: All 13 points lie in a circle of radius 1 about A or about B.

Corollary: Hence, by PP, we are done.